# Responsive design of Bootstrap textboxes

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have troubles with resizing my web page (which should be optimized for mobiles, tablets,...)
I decided to use Bootstrap and my idea is following:

A) On PC I would like to have two columns

```
 1. Label1 [TextBox1]   ______   Label2 [TextBox2]
 2. Label3 [TextBox3]   ______   Label4 [TextBox4]
 3. Label5 [TextBox5]   ______   Label6 [TextBox6]
```

B) On mobile/tablet it should look like this (right section under the left one)

```
 1. Label1 [TextBox1]
 2. Label3 [TextBox3]
 3. Label5 [TextBox5]
 4. Label2 [TextBox2]
 5. ....
```

I tried a lot of solutions but non of it led to success.. It did both columns just thiner but still side by side.

Answer (score 0):

A) On PC I would like to have two columns

```
<div class="col-md-6">Label1 [TextBox1]</div>
<div class="col-md-6">______ Label2 [TextBox2]</div>
<div class="col-md-6">Label3 [TextBox3] ______ Label4 [TextBox4]</div>
<div class="col-md-6">Label5 [TextBox5] ______ Label6 [TextBox6]</div>
```

B) On mobile/tablet it shold look like this (right section under the left one)

```
<div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12">Label1 [TextBox1]</div>
<div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12">Label3 [TextBox3]</div>
<div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12">Label5 [TextBox5]</div>
```

Label2 [TextBox2]
    ....

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap has the feature to have different layout based on the screen size. You can learn more about it from [Grid System](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) in Bootstrap.

You can put multiple classes to the element based on the layout you want.

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">Label1 [TextBox1]</div>
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">Label2 [TextBox3]</div>
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">Label3 [TextBox5]</div>
```

So what it will do is, on medium screen `(≥992px)` it will make two columns but in smaller screen `(≥768px)` it will have single column only.